# TextField in Compose : Double Tap to select text is not working

Tags: android, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

I am playing with Jetpack Compose.
In previous Android Views, we could double tap on a word in an EditText/TextInputLayout/TextInputEditText to select the entire word, and provide options like copy-paste, select-all, etc.
This does not work with Jetpack Compose TextField. The only way to make the copy-past/select-all options is with a long press on the TextField.

Is there a solution for this ?
(Tested with Compose stable version 1.1.1 and 1.2.0-alpha07)

Comment: I don't remember being able to do that by double tap in normal android Views. As far as I know it's always been by long tap. Maybe it even depends on Android version or device

Comment: Nevermind, it does seem to work in most apps. I just wasn't aware it was even possible like that. long tap was just my natural way to do it, but it actually might depend on device

Comment: I have same issue. any update?

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been reported on Googles's issue tracker thread here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137321832. It's currently assigned but not yet fixed

Answer (score 2):

It is a jetpack compose bug. You can fix the problem using this code:

```
@Composable
fun CustomTextField() {
    val textFieldValue = remember {
        mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(""))
    }
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val isDoubleTap by interactionSource.collectIsDoubleTapAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(isDoubleTap) {
        val endRange = if (isDoubleTap) textFieldValue.value.text.length else 0
        textFieldValue.value =
            textFieldValue.value.copy(
                selection = TextRange(
                    start = 0,
                    end = endRange
                )
            )


    }
    BasicTextField(
        value = textFieldValue.value,
        onValueChange = {
            if (!isDoubleTap) {
                textFieldValue.value = it
            }

        },
        interactionSource = interactionSource
    )

}


@Composable
fun InteractionSource.collectIsDoubleTapAsState(): State<Boolean> {
    val isDoubleTap = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var firstInteractionTimeInMillis = 0L
    LaunchedEffect(this) {
        interactions.collect { interaction ->
            when (interaction) {
                is PressInteraction.Press -> {
                    val pressTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    if (pressTimeInMillis - firstInteractionTimeInMillis <= 500L) {
                        firstInteractionTimeInMillis = 0
                        isDoubleTap.value = true

                    } else {
                        firstInteractionTimeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
                        isDoubleTap.value = false
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
    return isDoubleTap
}
```

You can use it for `TextField`, `BasicTextField` and `OutlineTextField`. Please, check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/fatemeh-afshari/dc7cc8231cad31955c73051968b34dd1) for more details.

Comment: Please state explicitly that you're the author of the linked gist. Any links to external content that belong to you must always contain disclosure.

Answer (score 0):

Double or triple click in the TextField is not working, but if you just tap the **blue water drop** of the cursor **once**, the **pop-up** will be shown.

[image: Pop Up]